# Copied bootstrap not working

Tags: html

I have this one page bootstrap that I have copied, but when I try to copy the same section page, the copied section page is not performing the classes.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the working code:

```
<section id="work" class="page-section page">


    <div class="container">
        <div class="heading text-center">
          <h2>Experimental Learning</h2>
          <p></p>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div id="portfolio">
              <ul class="filters list-inline text-center">
                <li> <a class="active" data-filter="*" href="#">All</a> </li>
                <li> <a data-filter=".academic" href="#">Academic</a> </li>
                <li> <a data-filter=".sales" href="#">Sales & Freelance</a> </li>
                <li> <a data-filter=".bpo" href="#">BPO</a> </li>
              </ul>
              <ul class="items list-unstyled clearfix animated fadeInRight showing" data-animation="fadeInRight" style="position: relative; height: 438px;">
                <li class="item academic" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;"> <a href="images/work/sol.jpg" class="fancybox"> <img src="images/work/sol.jpg" style="width:304px;height:228px;" alt="">
                  <div class="overlay"> <span>Solaire Hotel & Resort Casino</span> </div>
                  </a> </li>
                <li class="item bpo" style="position: absolute; left: 292px; top: 0px;"> <a href="images/work/tele.jpeg" class="fancybox"> <img src="images/work/tele.jpeg" style="width:304px;height:228px;" alt="">
                  <div class="overlay"> <span>Teleperformance</span> </div>
                  </a> </li>
                <li class="item academic" style="position: absolute; left: 585px; top: 0px;"> <a href="images/work/sc.jpg" class="fancybox"> <img src="images/work/sc.jpg"
    style="width:304px;height:228px;" alt="">
                  <div class="overlay"> <span>Pierre Romancon Scholarship Grant</span> </div>
                  </a> </li>
                <li class="item sales" style="position: absolute; left: 877px; top: 0px;"> <a href="images/work/av.jpg" class="fancybox"> <img src="images/work/av.jpg" style="width:304px;height:228px;" alt="">
                  <div class="overlay"> <span>Avida Corporation</span> </div>
                  </a> </li>
                <li class="item bpo" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 219px;"> <a href="images/work/tt.jpg" class="fancybox"> <img src="images/work/tt.jpg" style="width:304px;height:228px;" alt="">
                  <div class="overlay"> <span>Teletech</span> </div>
                  </a> </li>
                <li class="item sales" style="position: absolute; left: 292px; top: 219px;"> <a href="images/work/fl.jpg" class="fancybox"> <img src="images/work/fl.jpg"  style="width:304px;height:228px;" alt="">
                  <div class="overlay"> <span>Freelance RealEstate</span> </div>
                  </a> </li>
                <li class="item bpo" style="position: absolute; left: 585px; top: 219px;"> <a href="images/work/x.jpg" class="fancybox"> <img src="images/work/x.jpg" style="width:304px;height:228px;" alt="">
                  <div class="overlay"> <span>Affiliated Computer Services</span> </div>
                  </a> </li>
                <li class="item academic" style="position: absolute; left: 877px; top: 219px;"> <a href="images/work/startup.jpg" class="fancybox"> <img src="images/work/startup.jpg" style="width:304px;height:228px;" alt="">
                  <div class="overlay"> <span>Benildean Startup Youth Day 2014</span> </div>
                  </a> </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

When I copy the same section page, its not performing the same functions in the classes.

```
    <section id="work1" class="page-section page">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="heading text-center">
      <h2>Exemplary Academic Work</h2>
      <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div id="portfolio1">
          <ul class="filters list-inline text-center">
            <li> <a class="active" data-filter="*" href="#">All</a> </li>
            <li> <a data-filter=".proglanproject" href="#">Programming Language</a> </li>
            <li> <a data-filter=".thesis" href="#">Thesis</a> </li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="items list-unstyled clearfix animated fadeInRight showing" data-animation="fadeInRight" style="position: relative; height: 438px;">
            <li class="item proglanproject" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;"> <a href="images/work/Picture1.png" class="fancybox"> <img src="images/work/Picture1.png" style="width:304px;height:228px;" alt="">
              <div class="overlay"> <span>LUA Steam Project Site Map</span> </div>
              </a> </li>
            <li class="item proglanproject" style="position: absolute; left: 292px; top: 0px;"> <a href="images/work/Picture2.png" class="fancybox"> <img src="images/work/Picture2.png" style="width:304px;height:228px;" alt="">
              <div class="overlay"> <span>LUA Steam Project Site Map</span> </div>
              </a> </li>
            <li class="item thesis" style="position: absolute; left: 585px; top: 0px;"> <a href="images/work/th5.png" class="fancybox"> <img src="images/work/th5.png" style="width:304px;height:228px;" alt="">
              <div class="overlay"> <span>Registration Page</span> </div>
              </a> </li>
            <li class="item thesis" style="position: absolute; left: 877px; top: 0px;"> <a href="images/work/th4.png" class="fancybox"> <img src="images/work/th4.png" style="width:304px;height:228px;" alt="">
              <div class="overlay"> <span>Contact Form</span> </div>
              </a> </li>
            <li class="item thesis" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 219px;"> <a href="images/work/th3.png" class="fancybox"> <img src="images/work/th3.png" style="width:304px;height:228px;" alt="">
              <div class="overlay"> <span>Customer Profile Page</span> </div>
              </a> </li>
            <li class="item thesis" style="position: absolute; left: 292px; top: 219px;"> <a href="images/work/th2.png" class="fancybox"> <img src="images/work/th2.png"  style="width:304px;height:228px;" alt="">
              <div class="overlay"> <span>Checkout DashBoard</span> </div>
              </a> </li>
            <li class="item thesis" style="position: absolute; left: 585px; top: 219px;"> <a href="images/work/th1.png" class="fancybox"> <img src="images/work/th1.png" style="width:304px;height:228px;" alt="">
              <div class="overlay"> <span>Product Dashboard</span> </div>
              </a> </li>
            <li class="item proglanproject" style="position: absolute; left: 877px; top: 219px;"> <a href="images/work/prog.PNG" class="fancybox"> <img src="images/work/prog.PNG" style="width:304px;height:228px;" alt="">
              <div class="overlay"> <span>HTML Shopping Site</span> </div>
              </a> </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: What does it mean the don't work? Is there some javascript code connected to that that perhaps you are not copying?

Comment: Do you mean when you copy it to a new .html file? If so it's almost certainly not working because you haven't included the CSS files on the new pages head tag

Comment: same html file sir @leemo

Comment: @Mr.Web im copying it on the same html file. the copied page is not filtering, not reading the class="overlay" and etc.

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I see. The copying on the same page creates an issue due to the same ID of the div, they are to be different.

```
<section id="work2"...
```

Same for

```
<div id="portfolio1"
```

Etc...

Comment: yes sir. its different, as you can see on the 1st code, section id ="work" and on the 2nd, its section id="work1". also the div id is different. portfolio and portfolio1.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to update the Javascript file telling it what to do. For example I have a Bootstrap one page template also which references a file in assets/js/[themename].js with:

```
 var filterList = {
    init: function() {

        // MixItUp plugin
        // http://mixitup.io
        $('#portfoliolist').mixitup({
            targetSelector: '.portfolio',
            filterSelector: '.filter',
            effects: ['fade'],
            easing: 'snap',
            // call the hover effect
            onMixEnd: filterList.hoverEffect()
        });
    },
```

As you can see it is using target selector `.portfolio` to identify the class that it needs to apply to. I believe you need to duplicate the section to also apply to `.portfolio1` in order for it to work.

You've already made the filter references match so everything else should be ok. Oh but depending on what you're doing you might also need to change the ID `#portfoliolist` also.